# The li:hover behaviour for my list is unpredictable?

Tags: html, css

I'll post a JSFIddle if necessary, that would take a bit of effort since I'm using a markup language, but go here: http://mixtape.meteor.com

- Add enough elements so that there's overflow and a scroll-bar appears
- Now try to check out the hover attribute for any of the list elements, they all appear out of place!

Below is the relevant CSS code.

```
.list_element .next_song{
    cursor: pointer;
    color:white;
    margin-top:-38px;
    margin-left:29%;

    display:none;
    position: absolute;
}

.list_element .destroy {
    cursor: pointer;
    color:white;
    margin-top:-38px;
    margin-left:32%;

    display:none;
    position: absolute;
}

.list_element:hover .destroy{
    display:block;
}

.list_element:hover .next_song{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: "Add enough elements so that there's overflow and a scroll-bar appears" - I can't see how to this. There's only 2 buttons on-screen and none of them add elements to the list.

Comment: Sorry, hit enter to add an element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add position:relative at element_style, so the position:absolute will fit into the container. And then the only work for you is adjust the align of those buttons.

```
.element_style {
    position: relative;
    ......

.list_element .next_song {
    right: 10%;
    ......

.list_element .destroy {
    right: 0%;
    ......
```

Comment: @Louis93 You should also remove margins, as it is absolute elements.